# Why $params gets the values from configuration file and not the value set as default?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-5.6

I have this is a piece of code which is part of a custom library for CI 3.1:

```
class NavigationMenu
{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct($params = ['config' => 'navigation'])
    {

        // this is where I read $params as an array of 10 values
        // and it shouldn't be since $params has only one key = config
        var_dump($params);

        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');  
        $this->CI->config->load($params['config'], true);
        $this->CI->load->model('nav_model', 'nav');
    }
    ....
}
```

The file 'navigation.php` have the following code:

```
$config['navigation_open']          = '<ul class="nav">';
$config['navigation_close']         = '</ul>';
$config['item_open']                = '<li>';
$config['item_open_active_class']   = 'active';
```

I have notice that `$params` passed to the constructor reads as:

```
array (size=10)
  'navigation_open' => string '<ul class="nav">' (length=16)
  'navigation_close' => string '</ul>' (length=5)
  'item_open' => string '<li>' (length=4)
  'item_open_active_class' => string 'active' (length=6)
```

Why not read as?

```
array (size=1)
  'config' => string 'navigation' (length=10)
```

**EDIT**

I am not using the library meaning not object are being created instead I am autoloading the library, simple as:

```
config/autoload.php
$autoload['config'] = ['navigation'];
```

This will cause the class constructor to be called any time I hit the index.php file of the application.

Is this a default behavior from CI? From PHP constructor and I am not aware of it? Or something is wrong in my code and I am not seeing it?

Comment: Read the [manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#manual-loading)!

Comment: @csabinho really? where exactly? because I've already read it and doesn't find anything helpful regarding this issue

Comment: `$this->config->load('filename');
Where filename is the name of your config file, without the .php file extension.`

Comment: @csabinho are you reading my code and understanding the problem? I am trying to load the file using just the file name as you can see in the parameter `$params` passed to the constructor and initialized by default as `['config' => 'navigation']` that's not working and that's the issue

Comment: Is the value of params the array with 4 elements or the array with 1 element? If it is the one with 4 elements, CI works like it is stated in the manual.

Comment: `$this->load..` expects a class name, not an array.

Comment: @Kisaragi that's not complete true, it expects and string withouth the .php extension and such string is the configuration file to be loaded, In my example I am passing `$params['config']` which is a string and still not working either

Comment: And how are you loading the library?

Comment: How and where you read `$params` array?

Comment: @DmitriyKorobkov here `$this->CI->config->load($params['config'], true);` notice `$params['config']` there I am reading the array

Comment: In fact, this code should be working fine, read [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#utilizing-codeigniter-resources-within-your-library) I am doing exaclty the same as in the docs :-\

Comment: @ReynierPM No, where did you get `array (size=10) ...`?

Comment: @DmitriyKorobkov that's the behavior I am getting, that is coming from the `navigation.php` default configuration file. There are 10 items I just grab four of them to show you

Comment: @ReynierPM WHERE did you read it? Where in your code. Please, post the whole code.

Comment: @DmitriyKorobkov take a look to the code again, I've added where I am getting that you're asking

Comment: @ReynierPM Post code, where you create an instance of `NavigationMenu`.

Comment: @DmitriyKorobkov done, look at the EDIT, I am not instantiating the library at all, just autoloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$this->CI->config->set_item($params['config'], true)` instead. Please, read [this documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) carefully.

Comment: This doesn't work either, try my code example and you will see. I am not trying to set a value to the configuration I am trying to load a default config file from a constructor parameter

Comment: @ReynierPM something overwrites your default function parameter, daclare it in function body.